# Switch to another button depending on a condition in ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am working on a project in ReactJS and I have the following function:

```
function moveChecker() {
      let i = 0;
      let arr = [];
      while (i < props.moves.length) {
          if (arr.includes(props.moves[i].moveName) === false)
              arr.push(props.moves[i].moveName);
          i++;
      return arr
      }
  }
```

It goes through an object moves and takes in all unique moveNames. Now, I also have this HTML button:

```
<button className={`actionBoxButtonGrey ${moveChecker().includes('DiceMove') ? "actionBoxButton" : ''}`}
```

The code does not work but what I am trying is, if moveChecker().includes('DiceMove') is true, switch to the button desing actionBoxButton which is in my CSS file.

Is there any workaround to use those conditions for a button?

Answer (score 0):

You have made the true a string type by putting quotes around it.
Try this:

```
<button className={`actionBoxButtonGrey ${moveChecker().includes('DiceMove') ? "actionBoxButton" : ''}`}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I actually had it that way, with using the boolean directly, but it still would not work. But I have logged the arr and diceMove is inside